# Where do I put my resources in Scala?

Tags: scala, resources

While studying using Scala with JavaFX I have met the following code in a [ProScalaFX example](https://github.com/jpsacha/ProScalaFX):

```
  val resource = getClass.getResource("AdoptionForm.fxml")
  if (resource == null) {
    throw new IOException("Cannot load resource: AdoptionForm.fxml")
  }

  ...

  val root: jfxs.Parent = jfxf.FXMLLoader.load(resource)
```

Where do I put the actual "AdoptionForm.fxml" content in this case? Unfortunately I am neither familiar with using resources in Java.

I use SBT as the building system and Idea as an IDE.

There is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832751/scala-and-sbt-storing-sql-in-a-resource) which suggests a way (putting the resource files in "src/main/resources" or "src/main/resources/packagename"), but it also says it doesn't work actually (needless to say I have tried).

Comment: I put my resources in `src/main/resources` using SBT 0.12.x and it works perfectly. Is it possible that your problem is related to the [difference between `getClass.getResource` and `ClassLoader.getResource`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6608795/1804173) and absolute vs relative locations?

Comment: Perhaps, @bluenote10. Would you be so kind to provide a working example?

Comment: not that easy since it's just all about the package/resource directory structure. You may try this: `getClass.getResource("/TopLevelResource.fxml")` and ensure that the file has the path: `src/main/resources/TopLevelResource.fxml` (prepending the string with a `/` switches from package-base to absolute resource locations).

Comment: Adding "/" has indeed solved the problem. Thanks, @bluenote10.

Comment: I hope you don't mind converting the comment into an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`src/main/resources` is the correct location for placing resources in a default SBT configuration.

However, one has to be aware of the [difference between `getClass.getResource` and `ClassLoader.getResource`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6608795/1804173). Using `getClass.getResource("AdoptionForm.fxml")` requires the file to be located in a path which corresponds to the package of the class.

For instance: If the class is located in `com.domain.utils` then the resource must be located at `src/main/resources/com/domain/utils/AdoptionForm.fxml`.

In order to switch from package-relative locations to absolute locations one can either use `ClassLoader.getResource` or just prepend the resource string with a `/`.

Example: `getClass.getResource("/AdoptionForm.fxml")` loads the resource from `src/main/resources/AdoptionForm.fxml`

Comment: Putting the resource to the package-corresponding path did't work though. My root package is just like `MyApp` and the only class (an object actually) is `Main` (`extends JFXApp`). I have tried `src/main/resources/MyApp/MainForm.fxml` and `src/main/resources/MyApp/Main/MainForm.fxml` with no luck.

Comment: This is strange. Are you running your example in SBT or in IDEA? In the latter case, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12133632/scala-getclass-getresource-returning-null) + [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11176969/intellij-how-to-make-non-java-files-copied-to-the-bin-directory-as-well) may help?

Comment: I am trying to use Idea to run this project. Thanks for the links.